# Bootstrap Select Plugin does not render in Angular ui router ng-view

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-select

I use the Bootstrap Select Plugin to create an extended select with input field and multiple selectable options. I use it in an Angular 1.5.3 application set up with ui-router. It does not work in the view where I need it. The code I include in that view:

```
<select name="jobdomainTeamId"
        class="form-control selectpicker"
        data-live-search="true"
        multiple=""
        style="display: none;"
        ng-model="data.detailView.jobDomain.teams"
        ng-options="team.id as team.displayName for team in data.detailView.teams"
>
    <option value="">No selection</option>
</select>
```

The attributes 'selectpicker' and 'data-live-search' should trigger Bootstrap to dynamically create a node that provides the extra functionality. But nothing happens when I add this to the Angular view - the select is not visible (style="display: none;").

But when I add the exact same code to index.html, commenting out the ng-view

```
<!--<div ui-view="body"></div>-->
```

Here the select works - extra DOM nodes are generated and functionality is as expected.
I included all necessary stuff - Boostrap.css, bootstrap-select.css,jquery-2.1.1.,bootstrap.js and bootstrap.select.js

It occurred to me there might be a conflict between angular dependencies and Bootstrap - I include

```
angular.module('app',[angular-storage','ui.bootstrap','ui.router','ui.router.modal','xeditable','angular-confirm'])
```

Does anyone have a clue what might block Bootstrap css / js here??

Comment: You can call `$('.select').selectpicker();` in `onInit()` method as first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that mixing JQuery + Bootstrap.js with Angular.js is asking for trouble.
Bootstrap (via JQuery) works by 'grabbing an element and modifying it'. Angular also modifies the DOM element -  is an Angular directive (as well as an browser-native DOM element). What I tried to achieve is impossible this way and i ended up using an Angular library (ui-select) that does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

you defined `style='display:none'` in your select so it's working as expected. if you want to hide it use the directive [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) instead, in some case you should use [angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for specific actions

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. This methods helped me. Hope it help someone else also
Install jquery on your angular project.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/jquery
```

import jquery to the component.

```
declare var $: any;
```

run the below code on ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); 

  }
```